# How to select multiple items in recycler view android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, multipleselection

I want to select multiple items in recycler view and when it is selected I want to set visibility as visible of a checkbox of that item. So, long I am able to set `onlongClickListner` using interface and handling `onLongClick` event in a fragment.

Whenever user performes long click on any item, app's `onCLick` logic is changed. Before long click app is opening the item in another activity but, after long click `onClick`'s logic is changed and can be set whatever I want. I want to check the checkbox corresponding to the item after long click. And want to add that from an `arrayList` which is loaded in recycler view.

**Fragment**

```
...
@Override
    public void onclick(int position) {
        if (!isSelectionMode) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullPhoto.class);
            intent.putExtra("uri", arrayList.get(position).getUri());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

            //Support fun to turn selectionMode on, onLongClick event.

    @Override
    public void onLongClick() {
        isSelectionMode = true;
    }
...
```

**Adapter**

```
...

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener {


        private final ImageView img;
        public CheckBox selection;
        OnImageClickListner listner;
        OnImageLongClickListener longClickListener;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnImageClickListner listner,OnImageLongClickListener longClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listner = listner;
            this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);          //onLongClickListener is set to all of the RecyclerView Items for once rather than setting on each item in BindViewHolder for repeated times
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);          //onClickListener is set to all of the RecyclerView Items for once rather than setting on each item in BindViewHolder for repeated times
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            selection = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listner.onclick(getAdapterPosition());            //Returning the current clicked position
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            longClickListener.onLongClick();          
            return  true;
        }
    }
// inner class ends


    public  interface  OnImageClickListner{         //Interface to generate call back when user clicked an image.
         void onclick(int position);
    }

    public interface OnImageLongClickListener{          //Interface to generate call back when user long clicked an image.
        void onLongClick();
    }

...
```

I this scenario, i am unable to understand how to implement a selection tracker.  I can get the adapter position with `getAdapterPosition()` and then I can remove the element from `arrayList` on that index. But, I want to highlight the checkbox at that `position`. In this case i am unable to implement the code.

**Things I tried**

I did try to pass the `View v` from `onLongClick(View v)` and then passing the `selection` checkbox to `onCLick()` event. But, It didn't work.

I want to select the items from recycler view and set visibility as `VISIBLE` for the selected Items.

------ **Update** ------

I am now able to set visibility of the checkbox as visible with the help of few edits in event methods.

**Fragment**

```
@Override
    public void onclick(int position, CheckBox selection) {
        if (!isSelectionMode) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullPhoto.class);
            intent.putExtra("uri", arrayList.get(position).getUri());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selection.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
```

Where `selection` is a checkbox passed from `MyViewHolder` class from adapter. But, because nature of the recycler view i am getting double selections. and one weird issues that after selecting items if I scroll down, selections will be changed randomly.

[image: Issue]

In this image as you can see, I only selected 4 images but, when I scrolled down, other images were selected as well and when I scrolled up again it messed my selected items.

**PhotosAdapter**

```
public class PhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    public Context context;
    ArrayList<ImageModel> arrayList;
    Activity activity;
    OnImageClickListner listener;
    OnImageLongClickListener longClickListener;

    /*===============================================================   CONSTRUCTOR   ===============================================================*/

    public PhotosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageModel> arrayList, Activity activity, OnImageClickListner listner, OnImageLongClickListener longClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listner;
        this.longClickListener = longClickListener;

    }

    /*===============================================================   OVERRIDDEN METHODS   ===============================================================*/

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {           //This methods returns single_view.xml as a view for RecyclerView.
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view, listener, longClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {          //Binding the uris with each view depending upon the position of current view.


        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(Uri.parse(arrayList.get(position).getUri()))
                .apply(RequestOptions.overrideOf(150, 150))          //It overrides the value of original image and reduces it to the visible thumbnail size.
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)          //Then it caches the reduced size thumbnail for faster loading speed.
                .into(holder.img));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


    /*===============================================================   INNER VIEW HOLDER CLASS   ===============================================================*/

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {


        private final ImageView img;
        public CheckBox selection;
        OnImageClickListner listener;
        OnImageLongClickListener longClickListener;

        public final SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;              ///////////////////////////////// ADDED LINE /////////////////////////////////

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnImageClickListner listener, OnImageLongClickListener longClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);          //onLongClickListener is set to all of the RecyclerView Items for once rather than setting on each item in BindViewHolder for repeated times
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);          //onClickListener is set to all of the RecyclerView Items for once rather than setting on each item in BindViewHolder for repeated times
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            selection = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();             ///////////////////////////////// ADDED LINE /////////////////////////////////
        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            listener.onclick(getAdapterPosition(), selection);            //Returning the current clicked position and selection checkbox to the implemented method.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            longClickListener.onLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);          //Returning the current clicked position and view to the implemented method.
            return true;
        }



        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ADDED LINES ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        boolean isSelected(int position) {
            return getSelectedItems().contains(position);
        }

        public void toggleSelection(int position) {


            if (selectedItems.get(position, false)) {
                selectedItems.delete(position);
            } else {

                selectedItems.put(position, true);


            }
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }

        public void selectAll() {
            for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
                if (!(selectedItems.get(i, false))) {
                    selectedItems.put(i, true);
                }
                notifyItemChanged(i);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void clearSelection() {
            List<Integer> selection = getSelectedItems();
            selectedItems.clear();
            for (Integer i : selection) {
                notifyItemChanged(i);
            }
        }

        public int getSelectedItemCount() {
            return selectedItems.size();
        }

        public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
            List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>(selectedItems.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); ++i) {
                items.add(selectedItems.keyAt(i));
            }
            return items;
        }





    }       //INNER CLASS ENDS

    /*===============================================================   INTERFACES   ===============================================================*/

    public interface OnImageClickListner {         //Interface to generate call back when user clicked an image.
        void onclick(int position, CheckBox selection);
    }

    public interface OnImageLongClickListener {          //Interface to generate call back when user long clicked an image.
        void onLongClick(int position, View v);
    }


}
```

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-selection-support-to-a-recyclerview--cms-32175 give it a shot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369913/how-to-implement-multi-select-in-recyclerview

Comment: Did you want multiple selection of the items?

Comment: @AnantaRaha Yes, but, with the interface i have implemented. I have seen many example in which devlopers are setting `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListner` in `onBindViewHolder` but, I found that this can cause issues if the user has large number of photos. So, I successfully implemented `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListner` but, cannot set visibility of the checkbox corresponding of item which is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is causing the double or multiple selections.
Recyclerview works this way, that views are recycled.

So you have to hide, check or uncheck each item everytine a view is inflated.
So in the `onbindViewholder` you have to `setChecked()` to true or false depending on your scenario.

My approach for this problem would be:
Instead of passing views to the  parent fragment, keep the check logic in the adapter this way:

```
if (isItemSelected){
          selection.setChecked(true);
}else{
           selection.setChecked(false);
}
```

By so doing, there will be perfect checking and unchecking.

**-- Update --**

Create a Selectable adapter class to provide the `isSelected()` method as follows

**SelectableAdapter**

```
public abstract class SelectableAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
private static final String TAG = SelectableAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

SelectableAdapter() {

    selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();

}

boolean isSelected(int position) {
    return getSelectedItems().contains(position);
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {

    
    if (selectedItems.get(position, false)) {
        selectedItems.delete(position);
    } else {

            selectedItems.put(position, true);
        

    }
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public void selectAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (!(selectedItems.get(i, false))) {
            selectedItems.put(i, true);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(i);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearSelection() {
    List<Integer> selection = getSelectedItems();
    selectedItems.clear();
    for (Integer i : selection) {
        notifyItemChanged(i);
    }
}

public int getSelectedItemCount() {
    return selectedItems.size();
}

public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
    List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>(selectedItems.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); ++i) {
        items.add(selectedItems.keyAt(i));
    }
    return items;
}

}
```

Have your Adapter extend the `selectableAdapter` as follows:

**Adapter Class**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends SelectableAdapter<RclAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

On the fragment use `toggleSelection` to set a position as selected or not Selected.

```
@Override
    public void onclick(int position) {
        if (!isSelectionMode) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullPhoto.class);
            intent.putExtra("uri", arrayList.get(position).getUri());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
// Use the adapter instance here
            adapter.toggleSelection(position);
    
        }
    }
```

Remember `toggleSelection` notifies the adapter and calls `onBindViewHolder`.

In the adapter: `onBindViewHolder` implement the selection logic to show and hide the checkbox.
If you only set it to `View.VISIBLE` and don't set it to `View.GONE` for the ones not selected, you will still have the same problem.

Comment: ok. This makes sense... but, i still don't understand how am i going to control `isItemSelected` from fragment... i can create a method like to set `true` or `false` and then i wil call it in fragment... but, how to check a particular photo at certain index? this part i am unable to understand... if you can then please explain it bit further with some code...

Comment: Please go through `PhotosAdapter` I updated in my question. As `Adapter` class is already  extending inner class i cannot make it extend other class. So, I placed the code you mentioned inside inner class. But, Inner class is static and android studio insists that it should be static if I made it non static, so the methods `getItemCount()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` methods are showing an error.

Comment: If you look at my code carefully you will see that you actually can work with it, Maybe I did not mention how you are supposed to extend the selectable adapter on the main adapter: This is how  `public class PhotosAdapter extends  SelectableAdapter<PhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder>` . Modify it that way, because what you are currently extending is extended in the selectable adapter.

Comment: Your last comment was removed or something.

Comment: I just asked if you use any social media or not.. Then i thought it might not feel good. so i deleted.