# how to handle clicks on multiple views on a recyclerview when using recyclerview.addonitemtouchlistener

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I wanted to implement multi selection feature in a recyclerview so that I can select multiple items and perform delete or share action on them. For this I added addonitemtouchlistener to my recyclerview but now single tap and menu icon click of recycerview item is not working.

I tried to use a method of RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener called onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent but I'm unable to solve the issue. Kindly guide me.

Here's the code of my MainActivity.

```
rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
            RecyclerItemClickListener(this,
                rv,
                object : RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener {
                    override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
                        if (isMultiSelect) {
                            //if multiple selection is enabled then select item on single click else perform normal click on item.
                            multiSelect(position)
                        }else{
                            onItemClickOfAdapter(view, position)
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onItemLongClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
                        if (!isMultiSelect) {
                            selectedIds = ArrayList()
                            isMultiSelect = true
                            if (actionMode == null) {
                                actionMode = startActionMode(this@MainActivity) //show ActionMode.
                            }
                        }
                        multiSelect(position)
                    }
                })
        )

override fun onItemClickOfAdapter(view: View?, position: Int) {
        if (!isMultiSelect) {
            val openFromThisPath = docAdapter.getItem(position)
            viewPdfFromAnotherApp(openFromThisPath.filePath)
        }

    }

    // Shows the menu for a specific pdf file which helps to rename, delete or share it.
    override fun onMenuClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
        //creating a popup menu
        val popup = PopupMenu(this, view!!)
        //inflating menu from xml resource
        popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_on_file)
        //adding click listener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.rename_file -> {
                    showRenameDialog(position)

                    true
                }

                R.id.delete_file -> {
                    askForConfirmation(position)
                    true
                }

                R.id.share_file -> {
                    shareIntent(this, position)//handle menu3 click
                    true
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }
        //displaying the popup
        popup.show()

    }

    private fun multiSelect(position: Int) {
        val file: PidifyFile = docAdapter.getItem(position)
        if (file != null) {
            if (actionMode != null) {
                if (selectedIds.contains(file.id)) selectedIds.remove(Integer.valueOf(file.id)) else selectedIds.add(
                    file.id
                )
                if (selectedIds.size > 0) actionMode!!.title =
                    selectedIds.size.toString() //show selected item count on action mode.
                else {
                    actionMode!!.title = "" //remove item count from action mode.
                    actionMode!!.finish() //hide action mode.
                }
                docAdapter.setSelectedIds(selectedIds)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the code of my Adapter:

```
//This adapter provides File Recyclerview with data.
public class RvDocAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvDocAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
  -----------------rest of the code---------------
    //convenience method for getting data at click position
    public PidifyFile getItem(int id) {
        return files.get(id);
    }

    // allows click events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;

    }

    public void setSelectedIds(List<Integer> selectedIds) {
        mSelectedIDs=selectedIds;
    }


    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClickOfAdapter(View view, int position);

        void onMenuClick(View view, int position);
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView pdfName;
        TextView pdfDate;
        ImageView pdfImg;
        ImageView menuImg;
        TextView pdfSize;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pdfName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_name);
            pdfDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_date);
            pdfImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_img);
            pdfSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_size);
            menuImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuImg);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            menuImg.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == menuImg.getId()) {
                if (mClickListener != null)
                    mClickListener.onMenuClick(v, getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
            } else {
                if (mClickListener != null)
                    mClickListener.onItemClickOfAdapter(v, getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
------------------------rest of the code--------------------------------------

    }



}
```

Here's the code of my recycleritemclicklistener:

```
package com.shivanshu.pidify;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null)
            if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                mListener.onItemClick(childView, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
                return true;
            } else if (childView.getId() == R.id.menuImg) {
                return false;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }

    private boolean isClickAllowed(View view) {
        // Customize this logic to determine which views should allow clicks
        // (e.g., check view IDs, types, etc.)
        return view.getId() == R.id.main_card_layout || view.getId() == R.id.menuImg;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You don't need to add additional listeners. You already have listeners that you can use to track selection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390421/how-to-select-multiple-items-in-recycler-view-android and https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-recyclerview-with-single-and-multiple-selection-5d50c0c4c739 for some examples of handling multiple selection.